# Move gcloud image from container registry to compute

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-container-registry

I've pushed a docker image to gcloud container registry.

I want to create a new compute instance, in the same project, using the image in the container registry.

Ideally `gcloud compute images list` would show images in my project's container registry.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does [`gcloud container images list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list) not suit your needs?